# Logitech c270 access camera driver from OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, driver, logitech

is there a way to access the camera driver from OpenCV to disable an image optimization?

When I started playing around with the camera I wrote a simple application to measure the FPS rate, but I was receiving only 15 frames instead of 30 FPS with 640x480 resolution as indicated in camera’s specifications.

I did some research and found out that I can disable the “RightLight” function on the “Logitech Webcam-Software” (additional Software from Logitech’s website). I did it and got 30 frames.

I would like to programmatically make sure that the “RightLight” function is turned off when I start my application without using an additional software.  Is there a way to do it?

```
void testFPS() {

cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

//cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_SETTINGS, 1); //open the settings menu


cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0);

int frameCounter = 0;
std::stringstream ss;

cv::Mat mat;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


while (true) {      

    cap >> mat;
    frameCounter++;


    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;

    double fps = frameCounter / elapsed.count();

    ss.str("");
    ss << "FPS: " << fps;

    cv::putText(mat, ss.str(), cv::Point(30, 30), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, cv::LINE_AA);

    cv::imshow("Win", mat);

    if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) { //esc
        break;
    }
}
}
```

P.S.

There is another strange thing (bug) that I have discovered. If I disconnect the camera and connect it again I only receive 15 frames and the “Logitech Webcam-Software” shows me that the “RightLight” function is disabled. However, in this case I’m only receiving 15 frames from OpenCV’s VideoCaputre object. To solve that I must enable the “RightLight” function and disable it again to make sure that I will receive 30 frames.